# Why do we have "... for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$" when we define a function after also giving a domain?

Tags: functions, soft-question, definition

I was reading about functions on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) wikipedia page and in the section titled 'Notation', they give a proper example definition of a function:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by the equation $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

The "for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$" isn't necessarily confusing me, instead, I want to clarify its purpose. Namely, it's there to further dispel any ambiguity of the function's domain right?

I read about partial functions on wikipedia as well and I believe it has something to do with this. For example,
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x},x\neq0$$

Would this be a partial function? I think not because what I belive that $x\neq0$ is doing here is the same as what the "for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$" was doing in the wikipedia example (right?). Sort of to say "Okay I may have given $\mathbb{R}$ to be the domain but *really*, and to avoid any ambiguity into thinking this was a partial function, its actually all $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$"

Summary question:

> What is the purpose of the "for all ..."? Is what I've said correct? If not, why not?

Comment: "$f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$" is formally incorrect for your second example. What is meant is "it takes real inputs and gives real outputs". I think mathematicians just get lazy.

Comment: @DavidP an example given in the same wikipedia page states: 
"For example, if $f$ is a function that has the real numbers as domain and codomain, then a function mapping the value $x$ to the value $g(x)=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is a function g from the reals to the reals, whose domain is the set of the reals $x$, such that $f(x)\neq0$" (Towards the end of the section titled "Definition"). Is this also formally incorrect?

Comment: 1. When specifying a function and the domain is not explicitly given, then the "for all $x\in$ S" bit is implicitly taken to be the domain.  2. When otherwise referring to a function, the "for all $x\in$ S" bit, in general, is just to indicate the region of interest/relevance, which is a (perhaps improper) subset of the domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the purpose is to signify that $f(x) = x^2$ holds for all $x \in\mathbb{R},$ not to specify the domain. Consider the following alternative construction.

Let $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $f(x) = x^2$ for all $x \in [0, 1],$ and $f(x) = x^3$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus [0, 1].$